# Play 2.4.x - Java: Unauthorized on login, no apparent reason

Tags: java, security, playframework

I have implemented a quite simple authorization using Security.Authenticator way and stuck with random (can't see any reason) 401 response (Unauthorized: You must be authenticated to access this page.)

**Basically it tells me I should be authorized for action which doesn't require to be authorized.**

```
@RequireCSRFCheck
public Result authenticate() throws Exception {
    Form<LoginFormData> loginForm = form(LoginFormData.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (loginForm.hasErrors() || (requireCaptcha() && !ReCaptcha.verify(loginForm.data().get("g-recaptcha-response")))) {
        return badRequest(login.render(loginForm, requireCaptcha()));
    } else {
```

............

I log in fine once. Press log out, try logging in again - and 401 error goes up.

Why?

Comment: Is the controller annotated with `Security.Authorization`?

Comment: The controller which is linked to action throwing 401 is not. It processed email and password and sets session parameters for user.

Comment: Found out by downgrading revisions that this is somehow linked to CSRF protection I added

Comment: Resolved: Applying CSRF filtering on a per action basis I didn't remove global filter class which added second token and confused the system.